# redirect_uri_mismatch When using OAuth

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, gspread

Im not sure why but when trying to use the following code I get ('Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid' and 'redirect_uri_mismatch') when the browser window opens:

```
gc = gspread.oauth(
    credentials_filename='auth/oauth_creds.json'
)
```

I have already enabled the needed apis and download the creds for the OAuth client IDs, not sure why I am hitting this error, this is my first time using gspread, in the past I used the normal libs that gspread seems to wrap, but it has been a while.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect uri miss match is one of the most common Oauth2 errors.   The redirect uri you have entered in google cloud console for your app must exactly match the one that your application is sending from.

There should be an error details link you can click on it will tell you the exactly redirect uri you should enter into google developer console.

[Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

Comment: Thanks you for the response! I just tried that but it seems the port number changes every time I run the code.

Comment: You need to fix your application so that it runs from a stack port.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that with gspread, for some reason it changes port. Ill make an issue on their repo.